# Trouble using namespace in SQL Server XML Data Type query

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-namespaces

For background see this question:

[SQL Server XML Data Type query issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415003/sql-server-xml-data-type-query-issue)

I'm trying to query against an XML object in SQL Server 2005. The query works fine when there's no namespace defined in the XML. However, when the namespace element is there I cannot seem to get the value for a node element. Here's an example:

```
DECLARE @xmlWithNameSpace XML
DECLARE @xmlWithoutNameSpace XML

SET @xmlWithNameSpace = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Feed xmlns="gizmo">
        <Product id="4444">
            <ProductId>4444</ProductId>
        </Product>
    </Feed>'

SET @xmlWithoutNameSpace = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Feed>
        <Product id="4444">
            <ProductId>4444</ProductId>
        </Product>
    </Feed>'

SELECT feed.product.value('@id[1]', 'INT') AS productId  
FROM @xmlWithNameSpace.nodes('declare namespace ns="gizmo"; /ns:Feed/ns:Product') feed(product)

UNION ALL

SELECT feed.product.value('ProductId[1]', 'INT') AS productId  
FROM @xmlWithNameSpace.nodes('declare namespace ns="gizmo"; /ns:Feed/ns:Product') feed(product)

UNION ALL

SELECT feed.product.value('@id[1]', 'INT') AS productId 
FROM @xmlWithoutNameSpace.nodes('/Feed/Product') feed(product)

UNION ALL

SELECT feed.product.value('ProductId[1]', 'INT') AS productId 
FROM @xmlWithoutNameSpace.nodes('/Feed/Product') feed(product)
```

This returns

```
4444  
NULL  
4444  
4444
```

What am I doing wrong to get the value of the ProductId node (4444) when the namespace is in use?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is I have to define the node element I'm trying to access with the namespece as well. All of these samples return 4444 as expected:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('gizmo' AS nsWithXNS)

SELECT feed.product.value('@id[1]', 'INT') AS productId 
FROM @xmlWithNameSpace.nodes('/nsWithXNS:Feed/nsWithXNS:Product') feed(product)

UNION ALL

SELECT feed.product.value('nsWithXNS:ProductId[1]', 'INT') AS productId 
FROM @xmlWithNameSpace.nodes('/nsWithXNS:Feed/nsWithXNS:Product') feed(product)

UNION ALL

SELECT feed.product.value('@id[1]', 'INT') AS productId 
FROM @xmlWithNameSpace.nodes('declare namespace ns="gizmo"; /ns:Feed/ns:Product') feed(product)

UNION ALL

SELECT feed.product.value('declare namespace ns="gizmo"; ns:ProductId[1]', 'INT') AS productId 
FROM @xmlWithNameSpace.nodes('declare namespace ns="gizmo"; /ns:Feed/ns:Product') feed(product)
```

Thanks for reading and I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: The top portion question works great, but the bottom portion (with the WITH keyword) throws a syntax error in SQL-Server-2012  -- Any ideas RP?

Comment: Try adding a semi-colon before the WITH. I hope that helps.